# How to override routes extending a Controller in Symfony2

Tags: symfony, routes, symfony-2.3, extends

I created a BaseController to make generic REST Api calls, but in some cases, I need to extends it and change some code on it.

```
class BaseController extends Controller {

    /**
     * @Route("/api/{entity_name}")
     * @Method({"GET"})
     * @Template()
     */
    public function indexAction($entity_name) {
        $inflector = new Inflector();
        $class_name = ucfirst($inflector->camelize($entity_name));

        $entities = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager()->getRepository('AppApiBundle:' . $class_name)->findAll();
        $serializer = $this->get('jms_serializer');
        return new JsonResponse($serializer->serialize($entities, 'json'), 200);
    }

    /**
     * @Route("/api/{entity_name}/{id}")
     * * @Method({"GET"})
     * @Template()
     */
    public function getAction($entity_name, $id) {
        $inflector = new Inflector();
        $class_name = ucfirst($inflector->camelize($entity_name));

        $entitiy = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager()->getRepository('AppApiBundle:' . $class_name)->find($id);
        $serializer = $this->get('jms_serializer');
        return new JsonResponse($serializer->serialize($entitiy, 'json'), 200);
    }

    /**
     * @Route("/api/{entity_name}")
     * @Method({"POST"})
     * @Template()
     */
    public function postAction($entity_name) {
        return array(
                // ...
        );
    }

    /**
     * @Route("/api/{entity_name}/{id}")
     * @Method({"PUT"})
     * @Template()
     */
    public function putAction($entity_name, $id) {
        return array(
                // ...
        );
    }

    /**
     * @Route("/api/{entity_name}/{id}")
     * @Method({"DELETE"})
     * @Template()
     */
    public function deleteAction($entity_name, $id) {
        return array(
                // ...
        );
    }

}



    class CountryController extends BaseController {

    /**
     * @Route("/api/country")
     * @Method({"GET"})
     * @Template()
     */
    public function getAllAction() {
        /**
         * Another business rules here
         */
        return array();
    }
}
```

Then, if I call `"/api/country"` Symfony2 calls the BaseController's `"/api/{entity_name}"` route instead of the overrided route CountryController's `"/api/country"`.

Does someone know how to solve this issue?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Symfony checks the routes in the order it encounters them. You'll need to change to order of the entries in your routing configuration file.

Alternatively add a requirement parameter to your `@Route` annotation that excludes `'country'` as a possible match.